# How to correctly distribute requests among instances on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have an API that receives 4 simultaneous requests, each one of them handles many promises and take at least 30 seconds to complete. I'd like to distribute those requests among instances using the load balance. I've set in Capacity > Instances a minimum of 4 instances for that to happen, but that did not quite go as I planned for none of the requests reached the second, third of forth instance.

Comment: Do you have "session stickiness" enabled in the load balancer?  That's what it sounds like from your description.

Comment: It's actually the opposite, I don't want all requests from a user to go to the same instance, I want them to spread as much as possible. That is: user makes 4 requests, each request goes for a differente instance

Comment: Actually I asked because, as you say, you *don't* want that enabled.

Comment: Hello @SávioMuniz , have you ever found how to evenly distribute requests ?